# ThreeJS Blender Export Anisotropic

Tags: three.js, textures, blender

How would I specify the level of anisotropic filtering for a texture exported from Blender to ThreeJS?

Answer (score 0):

It's the "Filter Size" setting under "Image Sampling" for anyone else that wants to know.